# How do I modify error messages from Passport OAuth in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel 5.3 for a REST server that a mobile app connects to. I've already customized the exception handler for most Laravel errors and that's working the way I like.

However, OAuth errors come back ugly. Example:

```
{
    "error":"invalid_credentials",
    "message":"The user credentials were incorrect."
}
```

Apparently, I'm not the only one bothered by the error code with underscores -- I only have a handful of beta testers and they've already reported this as a "bug."

Passport seems to circumvent the regular error handler and go through `League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException` instead. These ugly error messages are hard-coded into that file.

```
public static function invalidCredentials()
{
    return new static('The user credentials were incorrect.', 6, 'invalid_credentials', 401);
}
```

I've seriously tried like a dozen approaches to extend/override OAuthServerException, but I just can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

To modify error messages from Passport one way would be to extend the Passport base classes and similarly the OAuthException methods as you've attempted. [Here's a reasonable explanation of how to do this.](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/289#issuecomment-291645481) I was trying to do this for something similar but in my case found it was overkill and went for something simpler.

However, if the issue is how you display the error in your mobile application one approach could be to map those errors to something more desirable rather than using them directly to report to your users (the following is pseudo-code as I'm not sure what your mobile app is coded in):

```
function handleErrorResponse(response) {
    var errorMap = {
        "invalid_credentials": "Username or password was incorrect." 
    };

    return errorMap[response.error];
}
```

In this way League\OAuth2\Server is your source of truth and your app simply translates those base messages when reporting to the user. Hope it helps!